# How do I interpret the completion of $C_{c}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be the vector space completion of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$  under the norm
$$
\|u\|_{X}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|Du|^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
I'm trying to show that the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is a proper subset of $X$. However I'm not even sure what the completion of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ looks like. I only know the fact that it is the closure of its image under the canonical embedding $*:C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to (C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n))^{**}$.

Comment: It corresponds to all the functions with $X$ norm finite that are the limit of a sequence of functions in $C^\infty_c$. Some properties such as the fact that it converges to $0$ at infinity will be conserved under taking such limit. This rules out nonzero constant functions

Comment: Thank you for the swift response @LL 3.14 . Is there somewhere I can find that functions in the completion vanish at infinity?

Comment: @LL3.14 $\sum_{k\ge 1} \phi(\frac{x-3^k}{2^k})$ is in this space and it doesn't converge to $0$ at $\infty$

Comment: Why do you think this is not $W^1$? It seems like $W^1$ to me, and Wikipedia seems to agree: see the section **Approximation by Smooth Functions" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The norm in question does not include the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: @MaoWao ok, thanks

Comment: @MaoWao Are you saying that it is possible to approximate constants functions by $C^\infty_c$ functions in this norm ?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, I think that's true. However, I messed up something in my answer and I don't have time to fix the details now. It's definitively true in 1D, where you can take a mollified version of $\phi_k(x)=(1-d(x,B_k(0))/k)_+$.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $X$ is $L^2(\Bbb{R}^n,\|x\|)$:  my argument is mostly that $C^\infty_c$ is dense in the Schwartz space for this norm, so on the Fourier side we can approximate $f\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^n,\|x\|)$ by $f_k=f 1_{1/k<|x|<k} \ast k^{2n} \phi( k^2 x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n-0)$ with $\phi \in C^\infty_c,\int \phi=1$

Comment: @MaoWao Oh indeed, interesting! I am really curious about the higher dimensions then, as the Sobolev embedding tells nothing in dimension $1$ about the decay. But indeed, in the usual assumptions when $n>2$, you need some decay at infinity to apply Sobolev's embeddings (Like the set $\{x : f(x) > C\}$ has to be finite for any $C>0$)

Comment: I follow the reasoning of why non-zero constant functions should be in the completion, but won’t their inclusion mean that we no long have a norm but instead a semi-norm?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer. Let $n>2$. Then, for any $f∈ C^\infty_c$, the following inequality (Sobolev's embeddings) holds
$$
\|f\|_{L^p} ≤ C_{n} \|∇f\|_{L^2}
$$
where $p=\frac{2\,n}{n-2}$ and some constant $C_n$ depending on the dimension. Take $f ∈ X$ and for any $k\in\Bbb N$, take $f_k ∈ C^\infty_c$ such that $f_k \to f$ in $X$ (and so in particular in the sense of distributions). Then $S = \sup_k \|∇f_k\|_{L^2} < ∞$ and so $f_k$ is uniformly bounded in $L^p$. In particular, up to a subsequence, it converges weakly in $L^p$ to a function $g∈L^p$, and so it also converges in the sense of distributions. Hence $f=g∈L^p$. This proves that when $n>2$
$$
X ⊆ L^p.
$$

Comment: Am I missing something by thinking that we can approximate non-zero constant functions by $0$ in the $||.||_{X}$ norm?

Comment: In dimension $1$ or $2$ only perhaps?

Comment: I understand your proof. Thank you for that. I just can't get around the idea that a non-zero constant map (in any dimension) has a 0 derivative and so it vanishes in the $||.||_{X}$ norm and should be in the completion.

Comment: The intuition is that even if it has $0$ norm, it is far away from $C^\infty_c$ functions that are "close" to the function $0$

Comment: If c is a non-zero constant function couldn’t I approximate c with the zero function which is smooth with compact support? In this case ||c-0||=0.

Comment: Perhaps the non-zero constant maps don’t live in the bidual.

Comment: This is due to the fact that the $X$ norm is not a norm if you include constants functions. In the same way that you identify functions that are equal almost everywhere, you should identify all functions up to a constant. A constant function is then in the equivalence class of the function $0$.